# How to test Spring transactions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-transactions

I'm working to a project with Spring Boot 2.1.0 and I've the following situation.

I've the following repository

```
@Repository
public interface ActivityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Activity, Long> {

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("") // Imagine a query
    void updateBacklogStatusAge();

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("QUERY 2") // Imagine a query
    void updateNextStatusAge();

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("QUERY 3") // Imagine a query
    void updateInProgressStatusAge();
}
```

and the following component

```
@Component
public class ColumnAgeJob {

    private final ActivityRepository activityRepository;

    public ColumnAgeJob(final ActivityRepository pActivityRepository) {
        activityRepository = pActivityRepository;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void update() {
        activityRepository.updateBacklogStatusAge();
        activityRepository.updateNextStatusAge();
        activityRepository.updateInProgressStatusAge();
    }
}
```

Now I want to test if the transactional annotation is working.

Basically my goal is to check if a runtimeException raised during the updateInProgressStatusAge() call will cause a rollback of updateNextStatusAge and updateBacklogStatusAge modifications.

How can I do that?
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Mockito in order to change the behaviour of your service or repository by using @SpyBean or @MockBean.

Unfortunately @SpyBean do not works on JPA repository (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7033, this issue is for Spring boot 1.4.1, but I have the same problem with 2.0.3.RELEASE)

As workaround you can create a test configuration to create manually your mock:

```
@Configuration
public class SpyRepositoryConfiguration {

   @Primary
   @Bean
   public ActivityRepository spyActivityRepository(final ActivityRepository real) 
      return Mockito.mock(ActivityRepository.class, AdditionalAnswers.delegatesTo(real));
   }
}
```

And in your test:

```
@Autowired
private ActivityRepository activityRepository;
....
@Test
public void testTransactional() {
    Mockito.doThrow(new ConstraintViolationException(Collections.emptySet())).when(activityRepository).updateInProgressStatusAge();

    activityRepository.updateBacklogStatusAge();
    activityRepository.updateNextStatusAge();
    activityRepository.updateInProgressStatusAge();

    // verify that rollback happens
}
```

Comment: The inability to use `@SpyBean` on a repository [has been addressed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7033#event-5027183603), and is set to be released with Spring Boot 2.5.3.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your method to test your transactional annotation.

```
@Transactional
public void update() {
    activityRepository.updateBacklogStatusAge();
    activityRepository.updateNextStatusAge();
    throw Exception();
    activityRepository.updateInProgressStatusAge();
}
```

This will simulate your desired scenario.

Comment: I see two problems on this approach. 1. Exception is not RuntimeException and if not specified in rollbackFor will not rollback anything. 2. This approach is not reproducible during the build, and if in the future there're some regressions we can't detect him

Comment: Any RuntimeException triggers rollback, and any checked Exception does not. This means you can use unchecked exceptions. I assumed you just want to see your code is working. If you want to write unit test it has different ways. You can check these links : [link1](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-test-programmatic-transactions) , [link2](https://blog.apnic.net/2018/02/08/testing-springs-transactional/), [link3](http://the-music-of-time.blogspot.com/2012/10/writing-unit-tests-to-ensure-your.html). Main points are explained in these links.